# Is it possible te get a user from the ReactionCollector in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

It's about one month that i'm actively developing a Discord bot but I have a problem about grabbing users from a reaction with the ReactionCollector

I know that you can catch this with this example :

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd',(reaction,user)=>{
  console.log(user); //Return the user
  console.log(reaction); //Return the Reaction
});
```

But I want to create a complex system and I don't know if it's possible or not to grab the user with the ReactionCollect to do something that would look like this :

```
let reactionCollector = new Discord.ReactionCollector(messagefilteroptions);
reactionCollector.on('collect', (reactions,user,collector)=>{
  console.log(user); //Return the User
  console.log(reaction); //Return the Reaction
  console.log(collector); //Return the Collector
});
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for V11
for v12, see [tipakA answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61068833/8040287)

A [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector) is used to wait for a specific condition about reactions on a messages (a number of reactions, a certain time, ...). You have access to the reactions after the collector has collected the reactions.

You have an example [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector):

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

The collector will collect all  reactions. For every reactions, it will log the name of the emoji, and after 15 secondes, it will log how many reactions were added.

However, we can't access the user who reacted during the `collect` because the `reaction` is a [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction). This type has a property which list **all** the users who reacted, because it's linked to the message and not the event which was fired when someone clicked.
*note: you can access the last user by browsing the `users` Collection. Since it extend the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), it remembers the original insertion order of the keys. But it will work only for one reaction.*

However, the `filter` function has a `user` and a `reaction`. The filter function is used to filter what type of reaction you want to collect (for example, only from people with a specific role, or only one type of reaction, ...).

Here, if you want to log the user, you can do something like this:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(user);
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};
```

However, if you want to do something with the users who reacted, you can do it after the collector has finished collecting the reactions:

```js
collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(collected.forEach((reaction => reaction.users.forEach(console.log))));
});
```

Depending on what type of reactions you're waiting, you will maybe have to verify the users hasn't already reacted to another reactions on the message (to avoid using it twice).

Use the `ReactionCollector` if you have to wait reactions on a particular messages. If you want to use it for every messages, use `bot.on('messageReactionAdd',...)`

Comment: In Discord.js v12, I think you'll want to use `reaction.users.cache.forEach(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are outdated by now, as they are for version 11 of Discord.js.
Version 12 was released since then, and as it brings multiple changes, `Collector`s also got a "refresh".

Now, the `collect` event on `ReactionCollector` instead of giving reaction and collector itself, gives reaction and user objects.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 10000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`${user.tag} reacted with ${reaction.emoji.name}.`);
});
```

Comment: If you're aggregating `user` at `on('collect')`, wouldn't you also need to account for `on('remove')`?

Comment: Huh? Removing a reaction it completely irrelevant from adding it, maybe apart from the fact that you cannot add a same reaction twice.
The example code doesn't do anything else than displaying that "a user reacted with <an emote>".

Comment: If you're asking about "removing that user from cache", then it's not how it works either. User will be cached by the lib and simply collecting when that user would un-react wouldn't perform magic and remove from cache.

Comment: I believe my issue was that a user could click on his emote to remove it, then add the same emote back and be counted again. (It's been a while and that project was put aside.) Perhaps it is irrelevant to the question, but it's worth considering in a more robust solution.

Comment: Well, yeah, if the given example would *count* reactions, that indeed would have to be handled. However it simply notifies about reaction, so that wasn't necessary here.